# Kafka Streams messages not coming through after aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a Kafka Streams application that reads from a topic, selects key as a non-null field from record value, does a groupbyKey on the selected key and then aggregates all values with same key with a string initial value of "" (empty string). My idea is to collect all values with the same key as a single large string and write to the output topic. However I see that different runs of my code ( I change application id to consume from earliest of input topic) ends up with different size output topic. I have 128 Million records in my input, but the output topic can range from 1.3M to 45Million records. Is it my Materialized.with, or the way I am key-ing the data?!

Can someone help me understand please. Here is my code, I use a Kafka Streams binder (Spring cloud Stream Kafka binder) to read all the input data and then do below key-ing, groupBy and aggregation, and then use a `.toStream()` and put that data in the topic.

```
public class PRWSLoader {

    private String initStr = "";

    @StreamListener
    public void process(@Input("prws_input_channel") KStream<String, PRWSREPLICA> prwsKStream
    ) {


        prwsKStream
                .peek(((key, value) -> log.info(">>> input key: {} prwhn: {} VALUE: {} ", key,value.getPRWHn(),value)))
                .selectKey(((key, value) -> String.valueOf(value.getPRWHn()))) //convert Integer to String key
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(() -> initStr,
                        (key, value, agg) -> {

                            return agg + "::" + value.getSequence() + "|" + value.getName()+"|"+value.getCae()+"|"+value.getSoc()+
                            "|"+value.getSocietyMech()+"|"+value.getCdCat()+"|"+value.getPRWSn()+"|"+value.getContr()+"|"+
                                value.getPePerf()+"|"+value.getPeMech()+"|"+value.getPeSy()+"|"+value.getCdTer()+"|"
                                    +value.getCdSy()+"|"+value.getCdCon();
                        },
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .toStream()
                .peek(((key, value) -> log.info(">>> output key: {} VALUE: {} ", key,value)))
                .to("APRADB_PRWS_MERGED");


    }

}
```

Interestingly, I see that in a **healthy run my output topic** and the changelog topic count are similar, but in an **abnormal run** like in the picture attached below, I see the output topic has considerably less messages than changelog. Here is a view from AKHQ of my output topic, changelog, repartition topics. I also see a weird thing happen where my output topic starts decreasing in count for some reason like it reached 2.5million and started to decrease.
All my topics have infinite retention, I set `retention.ms` to -1 for output and changelog topics. We are running on AWS MSK Kafka with 3 brokers,  all topics have 3 partitions and 2 in sync replicas. Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA

[image]

Here is my application config application.yaml, should I set something here may be that I am missing?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: https://kafka.internal.org:8081
      bindings:
        prws_input_channel:
          destination: APRADB_VW_PRWSREPLICA

      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            applicationId: ${APP_ID}
            brokers: ${CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
            configuration:
              max.request.size: 5242880
              schema.registry.url: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
              security:
                protocol: ${CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL}
              sasl:
                mechanism: ${CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM}
                jaas:
                  config: ${CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG}
              commit.interval.ms: ${COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS}
              state.dir: efs/${APP_NAME}-state-store
              default:
                key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
          bindings:
            prws_input_channel:
              consumer:
                keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
                startOffset: earliest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable local cache spring.kafka.streams.properties.cache.max.bytes.buffering: '0'

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).